# Error: Argument must be a dense tensor: range(2, 3) - got shape [1], but wanted []

Tags: python, tensorflow, som

I am trying to run an a code in Python for self-organizing map (SOM), which uses TensorFlow. I got the code from [here](https://github.com/spiglerg/Kohonen_SOM_Tensorflow/blob/master/som.py), but when I run it, I get an error:

> Error: Argument must be a dense tensor: range(2, 3) - got shape [1](https://github.com/spiglerg/Kohonen_SOM_Tensorflow/blob/master/som.py),
>   but wanted []

I think the code relevant is:

```
s = SOM( (3,), 30, num_training, sess )
```

and then:

```
class SOM:
    def __init__(self, input_shape, map_size_n, num_expected_iterations, session):
    input_shape = tuple([i for i in input_shape if i is not None])
```

or:

```
def initialize_graph(self):
    self.weights = tf.Variable( tf.random_uniform((self.n*self.n, )+self.input_shape, 0.0, 1.0) ) 

    self.input_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (None,)+self.input_shape)
    self.current_iteration = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

    ## Compute the current iteration's neighborhood sigma and learning rate alpha:
    self.sigma_tmp = self.sigma * tf.exp( - self.current_iteration/self.timeconst_sigma  )
    self.sigma2 = 2.0*tf.multiply(self.sigma_tmp, self.sigma_tmp)

    self.alpha_tmp = self.alpha * tf.exp( - self.current_iteration/self.timeconst_alpha  )


    self.input_placeholder_ = tf.expand_dims(self.input_placeholder, 1)
    self.input_placeholder_ = tf.tile(self.input_placeholder_, (1,self.n*self.n,1) )

    self.diff = self.input_placeholder_ - self.weights
    self.diff_sq = tf.square(self.diff)
    self.diff_sum = tf.reduce_sum( self.diff_sq, axis=range(2, 2+len(self.input_shape)) )

    # Get the index of the best matching unit
    self.bmu_index = tf.argmin(self.diff_sum, 1)

    self.bmu_dist = tf.reduce_min(self.diff_sum, 1)
    self.bmu_activity = tf.exp( -self.bmu_dist/self.sigma_act )

    self.diff = tf.squeeze(self.diff)

    self.diff_2 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (self.n*self.n,)+self.input_shape)
    self.dist_sliced = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (self.n*self.n,))

    self.distances = tf.exp(-self.dist_sliced / self.sigma2 )
    self.lr_times_neigh = tf.multiply( self.alpha_tmp, self.distances )
    for i in range(len(self.input_shape)):
        self.lr_times_neigh = tf.expand_dims(self.lr_times_neigh, -1)
    self.lr_times_neigh = tf.tile(self.lr_times_neigh, (1,)+self.input_shape )

    self.delta_w = self.lr_times_neigh * self.diff_2

    self.update_weights = tf.assign_add(self.weights, self.delta_w)
```

The whole error message is:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\jakub\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py",
>   line 491, in apply_op
>       preferred_dtype=default_dtype)   File "C:\Users\jakub\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py",
>   line 704, in internal_convert_to_tensor
>       ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)   File
>   "C:\Users\jakub\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py",
>   line 113, in _constant_tensor_conversion_function
>       return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)   File "C:\Users\jakub\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py",
>   line 102, in constant
>       tensor_util.make_tensor_proto(value, dtype=dtype, shape=shape, verify_shape=verify_shape))   File
>   "C:\Users\jakub\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\tensor_util.py",
>   line 379, in make_tensor_proto
>       _GetDenseDimensions(values))) ValueError: Argument must be a dense tensor: range(2, 3) - got shape [1](https://github.com/spiglerg/Kohonen_SOM_Tensorflow/blob/master/som.py), but wanted [].
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\jakub\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py",
>   line 505, in apply_op
>       values, as_ref=input_arg.is_ref).dtype.name   File "C:\Users\jakub\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py",
>   line 704, in internal_convert_to_tensor
>       ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)   File
>   "C:\Users\jakub\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py",
>   line 113, in _constant_tensor_conversion_function
>       return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)   File "C:\Users\jakub\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py",
>   line 102, in constant
>       tensor_util.make_tensor_proto(value, dtype=dtype, shape=shape, verify_shape=verify_shape))   File
>   "C:\Users\jakub\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\tensor_util.py",
>   line 379, in make_tensor_proto
>       _GetDenseDimensions(values))) ValueError: Argument must be a dense tensor: range(2, 3) - got shape [1](https://github.com/spiglerg/Kohonen_SOM_Tensorflow/blob/master/som.py), but wanted [].
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\jakub\OneDrive\UTP\SztucznaInteligencja\SOM\SOM2.py", line
>   148, in 
>       s = SOM( (3,), 30, num_training, sess )   File "C:\Users\jakub\OneDrive\UTP\SztucznaInteligencja\SOM\SOM2.py", line
>   51, in **init**
>       self.initialize_graph()   File "C:\Users\jakub\OneDrive\UTP\SztucznaInteligencja\SOM\SOM2.py", line
>   76, in initialize_graph
>       self.diff_sum = tf.reduce_sum( self.diff_sq, axis=range(2, 2+len(self.input_shape)) )   File
>   "C:\Users\jakub\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\math_ops.py",
>   line 1236, in reduce_sum
>       name=name)   File "C:\Users\jakub\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_math_ops.py",
>   line 2656, in _sum
>       keep_dims=keep_dims, name=name)   File "C:\Users\jakub\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py",
>   line 509, in apply_op
>       (input_name, err)) ValueError: Tried to convert 'reduction_indices' to a tensor and failed. Error: Argument must be a
>   dense tensor: range(2, 3) - got shape [1](https://github.com/spiglerg/Kohonen_SOM_Tensorflow/blob/master/som.py), but wanted [].

Does anyone know why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 1):

I am having the same problem. I changed the

```
self.diff_sum = tf.reduce_sum( self.diff_sq, reduction_indices=range(2,2+len(self.input_shape)) )
```

to

```
self.diff_sum = tf.reduce_sum( self.diff_sq,2 )
```

to just try to get it to run. This was the result after 400 iterations: 
[Kohonen_SOM_Colors_reduce_sum_bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1scE5.png)